# Zsh の prompt expansion を Bash 同様の順番で行うには？

Tags: shellscript, zsh

Zsh の [prompt expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html) はどのタイミングで行われますか？　特に、他の通常の [expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html) と比較してどの順番で行われますか？

たとえば Bash 3.2.57 では、次のように長さを調べる関数に[プロンプト用のエスケープ](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Controlling-the-Prompt.html#Controlling-the-Prompt)が渡すと、エスケープが展開された後の長さが返ってきます。

```sh
bash-3.2$ pwd
/tmp/prompt
bash-3.2$ cat set_prompt.bash
length ()
{
    echo "${#1}"
}

PS1='$(length \w) \w$ '
bash-3.2$ source ./set_prompt.bash 
11 /tmp/prompt$
```

しかし Zsh 5.7.1 で同様のことをすると、prompt expansion を展開する前に長さを調べているような挙動をします。

```sh
prompt % pwd
/tmp/prompt
prompt % cat ./set_prompt.zsh
set -o PROMPT_SUBST

length ()
{
    echo "${#1}"
}

PS1='$(length "%d") %d$ '
prompt % source ./set_prompt.zsh 
2 /tmp/prompt$
```

つまり、Bash と Zsh でプロンプト用の expansion の展開タイミングが違うような気がしています。

Zsh の prompt expansion はどのタイミングで行われるのでしょうか？　上のように Bash と差異があるようなのですが、Bash 同様 command expansion より先に prompt expansion を行うにはどうすれば良いのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

Zsh のドキュメントには以下のように書かれています。

> If the `PROMPT_SUBST` option is set, the prompt string is first subjected to *parameter expansion*, *command substitution* and *arithmetic expansion*.

したがって、これら 3 つの expansion が行われた後 prompt expansion が行われるようです。

prompt expansion を先に行いたい場合、 `print -P` が使えます。

```sh
prompt % pwd 
/tmp/prompt
prompt % cat ./set_prompt.zsh
set -o PROMPT_SUBST

length ()
{
    echo "${#1}"
}

PS1='$(length "$(print -P %d)") %d$ '
prompt % source ./set_prompt.zsh
11 /tmp/prompt$
```